# Access raspistill / pi camera inside a Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, raspberry-pi, dockerfile

I've been trying out my Node.js app on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B using Docker and it runs without any troubles.

The problem comes when an app dependency (raspicam) requires `raspistill` to make use of the camera to take a photo. Raspberry is running Debian Stretch and the pi camera is configured and tested. But I cant access it when running the app via Docker.

Basically, I build the image with Docker Desktop on a win10 64bit machine using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM arm32v7/node:10.15.1-stretch

ENV PATH /opt/vc/bin:/opt/vc/lib:$PATH

RUN echo "/opt/vc/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/00-vcms.conf \
    && ldconfig

# Create the app directory
ENV APP_DIR /home/app
RUN mkdir $APP_DIR
WORKDIR $APP_DIR

# Copy both package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./

# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Then in the Raspberry, if I pull the image and run it with:

`docker run --privileged --device=/dev/vchiq -p 3000:3000 [my/image:latest]`

I get:

> Error: spawn /opt/vc/bin/raspistill ENOENT

After some researching, I also tried running with:

`docker run --privileged -v=/opt/vc/bin:/opt/vc/bin --device=/dev/vchiq -p 3000:3000 [my/image:latest]`

And with that command, I get:

> stderr: /opt/vc/bin/raspistill: error while loading shared libraries: libmmal_core.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Can someone share some thoughts on what changes do I have to make to the Dockerfile so that I'm able to access the pi camera from inside the Docker container? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need to run a `--privileged` container with access to host devices and host binaries, it will be easier and no less safe to not use Docker at all.  The `/opt/vc` tree is empty in your Docker image and when you run `ldconfig` it has no effect.

Comment: @DavidMaze I only run with `--privileged` because I couldn't find another way to access GPIO, not even with `--device=/dev/gpiomem`.

Comment: Where is this file `/opt/vc/bin/raspistill` supposed to be? Is it already in your Raspberry or do you want to take this file from inside the image to the Raspberry folder using volumes?

Comment: @ManishDash on my Raspberry I have access to that directory and raspistill is there.

Comment: @user3632710 Did you solve it?

Comment: @AntonBärwald, I still have to try using the rpi-raspbian image from balena. I plan to do so this weekend following this tutorial: https://www.balena.io/docs/learn/getting-started/raspberrypi3/nodejs/ . The plan was to build a simple Dockerfile myself with only the stuff needed to run the app on raspbian but I'm already spending too much time on this research so I'll just try out balena.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem trying to work with camera interface from docker container. With suggestions in this thread I've managed to get it working with the below dockerfile.

```
FROM node:12.12.0-buster-slim

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PATH="$PATH:/opt/vc/bin"

RUN echo "/opt/vc/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/00-vcms.conf

COPY "node_modules" "/usr/src/app/node_modules"
COPY "dist" "/usr/src/app"

CMD ldconfig && node /usr/src/app/app.js
```

There are 3 main points here:

1. Add `/opt/vc/bin` to your PATH so that you can call `raspistill` without referencing the full path.
2. Add `/opt/vc/lib` to your config file so that `raspistill` can find all dependencies it needs.
3. Reload config file (`ldconfig`) during container's runtime rather than build-time.

The last point is the main reason why Anton's solution didn't work. `ldconfig` needs to be executed in a running container so either use similar approach to mine or go with *entrypoint.sh* file instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try replace this from the Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo "/opt/vc/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/00-vcms.conf \
&& ldconfig
```

With the following:

```
ADD 00-vmcs.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d/
RUN ldconfig
```

And create the file **00-vmcs.conf**:

```
/opt/vc/lib
```

---

**Edit**:

If it still doesn't work, try loading a Raspbian Docker image for example [balenalib/rpi-raspbian](https://hub.docker.com/r/balenalib/rpi-raspbian):

```
FROM balenalib/rpi-raspbian
```